# How to solve massive rendering problems in Android development

Tags: android, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-design-library, android-designer

I'm currently working with Xamarin for developing an android app. The structure of the app is really simple yet but a big problem appeared concerning the rendering of my main page. First, it's important to know that I'm supposed to develop for target API 23 so Android 6.0. 
And every time I test my application on my Android 6.0 device via USB-debugging the design is totally messed up with my only (!) button duplicated many times and the textViews mixed up over the screen (As shown in the picture link below).

Even though I am new to Xamarin and Android (and C#) I have my settings (as I think) in perfect order. The minimum API level is 21, the target SDK version 23 (Android 6.0), my device runs version 6.0.1, the target compiling framework in properties is set to 6.0, the manifest is set up as I mentioned before and even my "Designer" window with the layouts .axml is set to v23.
I really don't know what to try next, because I want to start coding further. Would be nice if sb could help me out with that.

I have already tested the code of the app on a different API level (26 I think) and it worked perfectly fine with my Galaxy S9 in Debugger mode. Everything looked like it was designed in first place.
I also tried different AppThemes in  Visual Studio but not one of the 7-8 I tried worked in any way different except for the colors.

The android app does only switch when clicking the button, texthttps://imgur.com/i0xChVniew 2 into the current date and time. I'm really sure, that my code is not the problem.

[Picture: How it should look (In Xamarin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjWIN.png)
[Picture: How it looks on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db5ed.png)

Comment: You need to supply sample code to recreate the problem.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: To ask for clarification, imho there is no code needed. The problem doens't occur when i develop for target 8.1 or something else. Its the rendering i zhave major problems with. I cannot think of any code describing the rendering problem.
There are no further updates for that problem.